# SQL Server - SQL query to convert 0 or 1 or 2 rows into a single row with 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a schema as below

```
Test
--------------------
|   Id    |  Name  |
--------------------
|   1     |  A001  |
|   2     |  B001  |
|   3     |  C001  |
--------------------

RelatedTest
---------------------------------
|   Id    |  Name  |   TestId   |
---------------------------------
|   1     |  Jack  |   NULL     |
|   2     |  Joe   |   2        | 
|   3     |  Jane  |   3        |
|   4     |  Julia |   3        |
---------------------------------
```

To briefly explain this schema RelatedTest has a nullable FK to Test and the FKId can appear either 0 or 1 or 2 times but never more than 2 times.

I am after a t-SQL query that reports the data in `Test` in the following format

```
TestReport
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   TestId   |   TestName   |   RelatedTestName1   |   RelatedTestName2   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1        |   A001       |   NULL               |   NULL               |
|   2        |   B001       |   Joe                |   NULL               |
|   3        |   C001       |   Jane               |   Julia              |
```

I can safely assume that `TestReport` will not need any more than two columns for RelatedTestName.

The schema is beyond my control and I am just looking to query it for some reporting.

I've been trying to utilise the `Pivot` function but I'm not entirely sure how I can use it so that `RelatedTestName1` and `RelatedTestName1` can be `NULL` in the case where there is no `RelatedTest` records. And also since `RelatedTestName` is a `varchar` I'm not sure how to apply an appropriate aggregate if that's what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preparing Data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test
GO
CREATE TABLE Test (Id INT PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(10)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO Test Values
(1, 'A001')
,(2, 'B001')
,(3, 'C001')
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS RelatedTest
GO
CREATE TABLE RelatedTest (
  Id INT,
  Name VARCHAR(10), 
  TestId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Test (Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO RelatedTest Values
(1, 'Jack', NULL)
,(2, 'Joe', 2)
,(3, 'Jane', 3)
,(3, 'Julia', 3)
GO
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  TestId           = T.Id
            ,TestName        = T.Name 
            ,RelatedTestName = RT.Name
            ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.Id ORDER BY RT.Id ASC)
    FROM    Test T
            LEFT JOIN RelatedTest RT
              ON T.Id = RT.TestId
)
SELECT  DISTINCT
        C.TestId 
        ,C.TestName
        ,RelatedTestName1 = (SELECT RelatedTestName FROM CTE A WHERE A.TestId = C.TestId AND A.RN = 1)
        ,RelatedTestName2 = (SELECT RelatedTestName FROM CTE A WHERE A.TestId = C.TestId AND A.RN = 2)
FROM   CTE C;
```